# Error java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver

Tags: java

whats wrong with this code? when i run this file it says Error java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
        String url="INSERT INTO com_details( com_id ,com_name,com_add,com_phone_1,com_phone_2,com_email ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\refbill\\billing_system.db");
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(url);
        pst.setString(1,txtComId.getText());
        pst.setString(1,txtComName.getText());
        pst.setString(1,txtComAdd.getText());
        pst.setString(1,txtComPhoneNo1.getText());
        pst.setString(1,txtComPhoneNo2.getText());
        pst.setString(1,txtComEmail.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate(url);

    }catch (SQLException  | HeadlessException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(addcom.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the full stack.

Comment: Why are you setting all your values to the 1st parameter index? See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString-int-java.lang.String-

Comment: you shoudn't pass `url` to `executeUpdate` method

Comment: @FastSnail yes, I'm surprised this even compiles

Comment: what can i do do for this? @fastsnail

Comment: @Thilinajayakody I'd start by reading the documentation ~ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--

Comment: @Phil It compiles, because `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(String)` exists by inheritance. Trap for young players. The SQLLite error message is pretty poor. It should say something like 'missing value #1 in prepared statement' etc.

Comment: @EJP not sure what you mean by _"exists by inheritance"_. Can you point to any documentation for that method (no rush, I'm just curious)?

Comment: @Phil `PreparedStatement` extends `Statement`, and [`Statement.executeUpdate(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-) exists.

Comment: @EJP Oh, yeah. Right :) My Ctrl+F skills are clearly lacking today (and it's been a very long time since I used anything directly in `java.sql`)

Comment: @Phil  I always start by reading the documentation :-|

Comment: @EJP I'll show myself to the nearest burns unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with this code.

1. You should be calling `executeUpdate()`, not `executeUpdate(url)`. It's a `PreparedStatement`. It already knows what the SQL is, because you provided it when creating. If you call `executeUpdate(String)` it won't understand the question marks.
2. You need to set all six parameter values. At present you are setting the first one six times.
3. Both `conn` and `pst` should be local variables, as should any `ResultSet` variable where used. Otherwise the code is not thread-safe.

The SQLLite error message refers to (1). It is a pretty poor effort. It should say something like 'missing value #1 in prepared statement' or else 'syntax error at ...'.